# REST Design: What Http verb should be used to retrieve a dynamic resource?

Tags: rest

I have a scenario in which I have REST API which manages a Resource which we will call Group. A Group contains members and the group resource is dynamic - whenever you retrieve it, you get the latest data (so a query must run server side to update the number of members in a group - in other words, the result of the request is to modify the data, since the results of running the query are stored).

Given a *group_id* it should return a minimal amount of information like

```
{ 
  group_id: "5t7yu8i9io0op",
  group_name: "That's my name",
  size: 34
}
```

So a GET to this resource causes the resource to change, since a subsequent GET could return a new value for 'size'. This tells me it is not idempotent and so you should use POST to retrieve this resource. Am I correct in this conclusion?

If I am correct, do you think it is advisable to also provide a GET method that only returns the currently stored data for the group (eg. so the size could be out of date, even the name too). I suppose in this case I should return a last-modified date as one of the fields so that the user knows how up-to-date the resource is and can then elect to use the POST method...but then I am left wondering why would anyone do that, so why not ONLY provide the POST method and forget about GET?

Confused I am!

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]**

@Satish posted a link in his/her answer to the HTTP specs. In section 9.1.1. it ends with this sentence:

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

So in my scenario, the requester does not really care about the side-effect that the value for 'size' is recomputed as a direct result of making the request. They want the group information and it just so happens that to provide accurate, up-to-date group data, the size query must be run in order to update that value. Whilst making the request causes data to change implies this should be a POST, the user did not request that side-effect and so therefore a GET request would be acceptable and more intuitive, would it not? And therefore still be restful according to this sentence.

**[2nd EDIT]**

@Satish asks a very important question in the comments. So for others who read this I'll explain further about this problem:

Normally you would not run the group query to update its size from a REST request. As members are added or removed from a group, you would update the computed size of that group, store it and then a simple GET request would always return the correct size. However, our situation is more complicated in that a group is only stored as a query definition in ElasticSearch (kind of like a view in an RDBMS). Members do not get added/removed to and from groups. They get added to a much larger set of data (a collection in MongoDB). There are hundreds, potentially thousands, of different 'group definitions' so it is not practical to recompute size for every group when the collection changes. We cannot know when an item is added/removed to/from the collection which groups might change size - you only know by running the group definition who is in that group and what the size is. I hope that clears things up. :)

Comment: If a GET request alters resource state on the server, the system is not very RESTful

Comment: The line "so a query must run server side to update the number of members in a group" is confusing. Data is updated because of the request or some other means. If request is just running select query  to get the updated data then there should not be any confusion about GET or POST.

Comment: @supertopi that is exactly my point - if the GET request alters the resource state, then it should not be a GEt but a POST, right? That is the entire purpose of my question.

Comment: As Setila and Quentin point out, the resource state is not actually altered by a GET request.

Comment: @Adarsh I haved edited the post to clarify this line. Data is updated as a result of the request

Comment: @supertopi Just to clarify that in this scenario the resource state IS altered as a result of the request, implying it should be a POST. However, I have edited the question to point out the 'exception' concerning side effects, which implies it should be a GET.

Comment: @rmcsharry: As you are saying that data is updated (persisted, not cached) as a result of request, there should not be any doubt in using GET method.

Comment: @rmcsharry no, the data is not updated with your GET request. You do not send any data with your GET request, do you? You just get a computed value of current data, or as in REST we like to call: a representation.

Comment: @supertopi thanks for pointing out that no data is sent with the request, which is correct. The confusion arises about that the fact that a server-side process modifies data as a direct result of the request, which is why I was initially leaning towards it being a POST. But the 'side effects' of safe methods in 9.1.1 seems to indicate this is indeed a GET request

Comment: @supertopi In response to your first comment I would normally agree that this is true. But this appears to be a good case where state on the server does change as a result of GET request and the system is still RESTful - due to the 'side effects' clause in 9.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use GET.  Even if dynamic resource is changing, you did not request for that change through your request and you are not accountable for that change.  Ref: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: This is the problem - you did not request for the change directly, but you want the most up-to-date information for 'size', so it must be computed whenever you retrieve the group resource. So it is a side-effect of making the request, which leads me to think it should be POST.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Satish. This link is why I am confused and I have updated the answer to explain why

Comment: @rmcsharry More specifically you should read [section 9.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1) about *safe* methods. Being "safe" depends on wether the user could be "held accountable for the side-effect" or not.

Comment: @Aurelien I did read that thanks and I updated the question accordingly. The sentence I quote from 9.1.1. indicates to me that a GET request is probably the right answer, but I'm not 100% sure yet! ;)

Comment: Firstly please describe what "size" is.  Is it just a counter?

Comment: @Satish Yes, size is a counter (of the number of members of the group)

Comment: If I want to get the list of members of a group why would the size change?  You have described in your question the input to method but you have not mentioned clearly the domain.  Reason I ask this is for RESTful design along with bookish technical knowledge even domain is import for design.

Comment: @rmcsharry Please also consider that if the method is really safe, your service is not supposed to be "harmed" if there is not an exact match between client software requests and user interaction (because of cache and refresh).

Comment: @Satish The domain is a CRM, specifically contacts in a contacts database which are always belonging or not belonging to groups. As contacts are 'moved' around, they constantly enter or leave groups. So whenever you want to retrieve a specific group, you want to know the value of the property 'size' (at the time of the request)

Comment: @Aurélien Thanks for that consideration - in this case it would still be safe.

Comment: @rmcsharry.  I reread your edit "They want the group information and it just so happens that to provide accurate, up-to-date group data, the size query must be run in order to update that value. Whilst making the request causes data to change".  size query even though it runs and physically updates the value, that value has no significance.  Nobody can trust that value because another user still has to run the size query again to get value rather than reading from size value your query updated.  As a part of ACID property transaction which actually causes size to vary should update size.

Comment: @rmcsharry, Ok. Agreed that transaction may happen in remote database and size cannot be updated at 10 places.  My question is why is size you are updating in database when you run your "size query"?  It is derived value.  Your GET request does not change the Primary values.  And even if derived value for some reason is stored  and updated in database, they are valid only for your request.  Better would be to have a view and read size from view.

Comment: @Satish Normally you would be correct and that the size should only change as part of ACID operations. However, the data is in MongoDB, not an RDBMS so we cannot use a view. The problem is that a group is just a query definition (like a view in RDBMS) and members do not actually get added to a group, but to a MongoDB collection. You can only know if a member is in a group by running the group query - there could be hundreds of group queries, so it is not efficient to re-run them all every time a member is added or removed from the collection, so we only run them when requested.

Answer (score 4):

In your case when you do a `GET` you retrieve some information about the Group. You don't modify the group structure. Ok, the group **can be changed by an external entity** so your next GET may bring you another data. Am I right? Who modifies the structure of the group and when?

So you should use `GET`because the resource it will be modified from somewhere else and not by your call that tries to do a `read operation`.

**EDIT**

After your edited the question I just want to add that I agree about the side effects.
It matters if you **sent data or a change command explicitly to the server**  or you just read something and you don't have to pay attention for what the server side is doing to gave you the response. More intuitively:

```
GET - Requests data from a specified resource    
POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource
```

Comment: This is right. The data is changing because the number of members have changed, but the request isn't the cause of that change.

Comment: The data is changing directly as a result of the request because the requester wants the data to be accurate at the time the request is made. This tells me it should be a POST....still confused!

Comment: @Setila thanks for the Edit, the 'side effects' statement is key and I think it makes this group scenario an exception to the rule that GET requests should be idempotent. I am leaning more towards GET (and setting headers to ensure it is not cached)

Answer (score -1):

It is the combination of GET and POST. So you should use POST.

Refer : http://adarshdchaurasia.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/http-get-vs-post/

You should not use GET because if you use GET method then search engines may cache the responses. It may cause unintentional data update at your server side, which you do not want. GET method is meant to return content without updating anything on server. POST is meant to updated the things at server and return result against that operation.

Comment: No. If you don't want old data to be cached by search engines, then set apropriate cache control headers (not that search engines are in the habit of indexing JSON data in the first place though)

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I missed JSON part. :(   However if any update is happening on the server then it should not be retrieved using GET method.

Comment: The request isn't causing an update. It is just getting a computed value.

Comment: Except that the computed value is changing as a result of making the request - so therefore it should be a POST, shouldn't it? Even though that does seem counter-intuitive.

Comment: I wasn't concerned about caching because it is JSON data, but if the conclusion is that this should be a GET request then to be safe I would set headers as @Quentin points out

Comment: @Quentin I just want to clarify that the request is also causing an update, since the computed value (computed as a result of the request) is also persisted in the database as well as being returned in the response.

Comment: @rmcsharry — That's just caching. The request still isn't responsible for the data changing.

Comment: @Quentin If the request had not been made, the data would not have changed - however, I get that is not the same thing as the request being responsible (not directly, only indirectly). So the change is a side-effect of the request being made. I think the edit I have added to the question clarifies this case and as such we would not want it cached, since the resource should always return the computed value, not the stored value

Comment: @rmcsharry — Are you saying that *asking* how many members are in the group *changes* how many members in the group? Because, previously, it sounded like you were just counting how many members were in the group, caching the result in your database, then returning the answer.

Comment: @Quentin No I'm not saying that. The request will always cause the update query to run but the computed (and hence persisted) value may or may not change as a result. But I now see this as a 'side effect' of making the request, not the purpose of the request, and on the basis of 9.1.1 'Safe Methods' I think this is a GET request, not a POST.